# Different first/subsequent citations for 3~5 authors using `natbib` with `elsarticle`

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, elsarticle, apacite

In order to abide by the APA rules:

> Name lists with three to five names are shown in full on a first
> citation, and are abbreviated to the first name and "et al." on
> subsequent citations.
>
> Name lists with six or more names are always shortened to first name +
> "et al.".

With `article` documentclass, it can be achieved by:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

or:

```
\usepackage[style=apa6, natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

or:

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
```

with `\shortcites{...}` to get shorten citation for >=6 authors for the first citation.

but all of those **cannot work with** **`elsarticle`** documentclass.

I know the `\citep*{...}` can be used at the first citation to produce full authors for 3-5 authors, but not a smart solution.

**In summary, is there a way to use `natbib` package with `elsarticle` documentclass (using `BibTeX`) to abide by the APA rules mentioned above, e.g. how to edit .bst to achieve this?**

The MWE is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Threeauthor2015,
    title = {World of Movement},
    volume = {312}, 
    number = {1},
    journal = {Scientific American},
    author = {Threeauthor, F and Freeman, W and Rubinstein, M},
    year = {2015},
}

@article{Fiveauthor2018,
    title = {Mauris Turpis Condimentum Augue Nec Ultricies},
    volume = {19},
    journal = {Heliyon},
    author = {Fiveauthor, Jessi and Lupton, R and Albert, P and Alice, Eva and Staples, J},
    year = {2018},
    pages = {e00205},
}

@article{Sixauthor2022,
    title = {Balloon Comparative Systematic Review},
    volume = {222},
    number = {333},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Econometrics},
    author = {Sixauthor, R and Bond, J and Fritzell, P and Russel, J and Clare, L and Suma, J},
    year = {2022},
    pages = {1188--1199},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names} 

\begin{document}

\citep{Threeauthor2015} \citep{Threeauthor2015} 

\citep{Fiveauthor2018} \citep{Fiveauthor2018} 

\citep{Sixauthor2022} 

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

where the first

```
\citep{Fiveauthor2018}
```

should show all authors in pdf, e.g.:

> (Fiveauthor, Lupton, Albert, Alice and Staples, 2018)

Comment: Since (a) the `elsarticle` document class loads `natbib` automatically and (b) none of the bibliography styles provided by the `elsarticle` class can be said to implement the formattng requirements of either APA6 or APA7, you may need to edit the file `elsarticle.cls` to stop loading `natbib` automatically. Then, you could run `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` in your document's preamble to implement the APA6 rules for both citation call-outs and formatted bibliographic entries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Normally it is not recommended to modify .cls. And I try to avoid the apacite.bst, because it must load apacite.sty which defines loads of formatting commands affecting document structure. The apacite.bst is quite different from, and far more complex than, other normal .bst, not a good base to edit for different bib-styles. So I am seeking a way to add this different first/subsequent citations for 3-5 authors ability to normal "independent" .bst.